# Why does ActiveRecord has_many use delete_all instead of destroy_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I have a model which has many children. I was setting/removing the children as such:

```
mymodel.children_ids = [1,2,3]
mymodel.save #add the children
mymodel.children_ids = [1]
mymodel.save #remove children 2,3
```

This works just fine, but I just realized that none of the callbacks (i.e. `after_destroy`) are not being called on the children model.

After some digging, it turns out that the `delete_all` function is being executed, rather than `destroy_all`. As the docs correctly state, the `delete_all` function does not fire off the callbacks, so is there anyway to change this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I added the following monkeypatch to force the has_many through to perform a destroy_all, rather than delete_all. There might be a better way, so I'm open to suggestions.

```
module ActiveRecord 
  module Associations
    class HasManyThroughAssociation < HasManyAssociation       
      def delete_records(records)
        klass = @reflection.through_reflection.klass
        records.each do |associate|
          klass.destroy_all(construct_join_attributes(associate)) #force auditing by using destroy_all rather than delete all
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this solution still works in Rails 3.1.1? It's not working on mine, got `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Comment: I'm not sure...I plan on upgrading my app to Rails 3.1 in a few months. I suppose I will have to figure this out by then.

Answer (score 1):

`delete_all` is being executed... just because? That's what the Rails core team thought should be called in that instance. However, you could explicitly call the `destroy_all` method on the model's children, but not using that type of query. It looks like you're setting the child IDs directly, not using any `build()` or `destroy()` methods.

Yes, you can overwrite its functionality. You could patch it and put it in `/vendor`, rewriting the same block of code with `destroy_all` instead. Then use a `send` command to replace the base ActiveRecord functionality with your own.

Comment: I suppose I could just monkey patch the piece of code that handles this.

Any idea where that lives?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
mymodel.children.find([2,3]).each {|c| c.destroy }
```

will do the job. It's not exactly what you wanted, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I figured that I could just override the children_ids= function in the model class, and handle it there...but I was hoping there would be a cleaner/dryer way.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with callbacks. Solved it using alias_method_chain to override default setter.

```
  def product_categories_with_destroy=(product_categories)
    unless new_record? 
      (self.product_categories - product_categories).each(&:destroy)
    end

    self.product_categories_without_destroy = product_categories
  end
  alias_method_chain :product_categories=, :destroy
```

More details on alias_method_chain:

http://yehudakatz.com/2009/03/06/alias_method_chain-in-models/